# sessionId key not found in JSON object even though print of string shows this

Tags: java, json

```
String sessionCookie = req.getReader().lines().reduce("",String::concat);
JSONObject jsonObject =  HTTP.toJSONObject(sessionCookie);
String someString = jsonObject.getString("sessionId");
```

The value of `sessionCookie` is `{"sessionId":"foo"}`, however the line `String someString = jsonObject.getString("sessionId");` gives this error:

> org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["sessionId"] not found.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I should have done:

```
String sessionCookie = req.getReader().lines().reduce("",String::concat);
JSONObject jsonObject =  new JSONObject(sessionCookie);
String sessionId = jsonObject.getString("sessionId");
```